# How can I stop System.Uri from converting UNC paths to File:/// paths?

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, bitmapimage, unc

I am trying to set a WPF image control's source to a UNC path image.
My current code goes similar to the following

```
Button.Content = new Image
{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(UncPathAsString)),
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
};
```

However, instead of loading the UNC path of the format:

```
\\Machine\Folder\Subfolder\Image.jpg
```

Uri returns the path of:

```
File:///Machine/Folder/Subfolder/Image.jpg
```

I have tried creating a bitmap for the UNC path and then converting the Bitmap to a BitmapImage but the performance was too slow for the application. I.E. There are up to several hundred of these buttons being created, and converting the bitmap made load times horrible.

Comment: Don't  create or manipulate UI elements in code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.

Comment: And where is the problem? The image should load anyway, no matter how the remote file path is formatted. Can you open the image by just pasting the Uri string into Windows Explorer?

Comment: I have a remote System called `VAIO` and can easily load images from there by `image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\\VAIO\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"));`

Comment: @HighCore the buttons are created from a sql database, each one loads an image based on the field entry. The buttons are contained in a uniformgrid.

Clemens Strange that it works for you and not me. Have you tried viewing the value of your BitmapImage's UriSource?

Comment: @AndrewHaskell Regardless of where data comes from, my point still stands. DO NOT manipulate UI elements in procedural code. Learn MVVM. UI is not Data. If you need a dynamic number of repeating UI elements, use an `ItemsControl`.